# Python Pandas multiply based on columns and add suffix

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `DataFrame` objects which I would like to multiply based on the column names and output the new column with a suffix...

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=(5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

    A   B   C   D   E
0   6   2   1   7   2
1   0   0   2   1   8
2   7   2   6   6   9
3   2   5   5   1   3
4   9   1   6   7   4

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(5,3)), columns=list('ABC'))

    A   B   C
0   2   1   2
1   7   5   1
2   2   1   4
3   7   8   5
4   9   2   2
```

I would like the output to be listed as with columns `A_x`, `B_x` and `C_x` being the product of the aligning columns in `df1` and `df2`

```
    A   B   C   A_x  B_x    C_x    D    E
0   6   2   1   12     2    2      7    2
1   0   0   2   0      0    2      1    8
2   7   2   6   14     2    24     6    9
3   2   5   5   14     40   25     1    3
4   9   1   6   81     2    12     7    4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) for get same columns names and then multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html), add [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) `df1`:

```
cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
df = df1[cols].mul(df2[cols], axis=1).add_suffix('_x')
df = pd.concat([df1, df], axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D   E  A_x  B_x  C_x
0  6  2  1  7   2   12    2    2
1  0  0  2  1   8    0    0    2
2  7  2  6  6   9   14    2   24
3  2  5  5  1   3   14   40   25
4  9  1  6  7  42   81    2   12
```

If need change order of columns:

```
cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
df = df1[cols].mul(df2[cols], axis=1).add_suffix('_x')
cols1 = cols.tolist() + \
        df.columns.tolist() +  \
        df1.columns.difference(df2.columns).tolist()
df = pd.concat([df1, df], axis=1)

print (df[cols1])
   A  B  C  A_x  B_x  C_x  D   E
0  6  2  1   12    2    2  7   2
1  0  0  2    0    0    2  1   8
2  7  2  6   14    2   24  6   9
3  2  5  5   14   40   25  1   3
4  9  1  6   81    2   12  7  42
```

Comment: `.add_suffix()` is exactly what I was looking for!